# Change month name to Indonesian language in cakephp 2+

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to change language in default datetime selector

i have set below configuration in bootstrap.php

```
 Configure::write('Config.language', 'id');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'id');
```

...app\Locale\id\LC_MESSAGES\default.po file contains

```
 msgid "january"
 msgstr "januari"
```

My view file contains

```
 $from_date_options = array();
 $from_date_options['type'] = 'datetime';
 $from_date_options['div'] = 'clearfix';
 $from_date_options['div'] = 'input text required';
 $from_date_options['orderYear'] = 'asc';
 $from_date_options['minYear'] = date('Y') -10;
 $from_date_options['maxYear'] = date('Y') +10;
 $from_date_options['label'] = __('Starts');                                                                
 $from_date_options['timeFormat'] = '24';
 $from_date_options['dateFormat'] = 'DMY';
 $from_date_options['separator'] = '/';

echo $this->Form->input('CustomPricePerTypestart_date', $from_date_options);
```

Month not translated. Where im going wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Try adding it to cake.pot not default pot

Comment: thanks DIDoS with your clue only i found answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer,
bootstrap file needs only language configure. and it accepts below two.

```
 Configure::write('Config.language', 'id');
 Configure::write('Config.language', 'ind');
```

File structure should be

```
...app\Locale\ind\LC_MESSAGES\cake.po
```